# Replacing Text "The Map" with Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change all of the text is "`#`", "`/`", and "`+`" using JavaScript or jQuery.

How to change this to appear on `<div id="results"></div>` ?

`#` => `hash`

`/` => `or`

`+` => `plus`

**Example:**

before: `G#7+`

after: `Ghash7plus`

and

before: `Fm/Ab`

after: `FmorAb`

**My Code:**

```
<span class="teks">A</span>
<span class="teks">B</span>
<span class="teks">C#</span>
<span class="teks">G#7+</span>
<span class="teks">Fm/Ab</span>

<h3>RESULTS</h3>
<div id="results"></div>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
var textValues = $('.teks').map(function() {
thisCrd1 = $(this).html();
thisCrd2 = $(this).html();
    return "<div class='crd_"+ thisCrd1 + "'>"+ thisCrd2 + "</div>";
}).get();

$('#results').html(textValues);
</script>
```

I have tried many times, but apparently not getting the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code to replace `#`, `\` and `+` with corresponding text (provided other code is fine),

```
var thisCrd2 = thisCrd1.replace("#", "hash").replace("/", "or").replace("+", "plus");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace()` function on the text of the `span` elements along with a global regex to replace all instance of the required characters.

To make this simple to maintain you can place the characters to be replaced along with the replacements in to an object which you loop through. Try this:

```js
var lookup = {
  '#': 'hash',
  '+': 'plus',
  '/': 'or'
}

$('span').text(function(_, t) {
  Object.keys(lookup).forEach(function(k) {
    t = t.replace(new RegExp('\\' + k, 'g'), lookup[k]);
  });
  return t;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="teks">A</span>
<span class="teks">B</span>
<span class="teks">C#</span>
<span class="teks">G#7+</span>
<span class="teks">Fm/Ab</span>
```

To update your `#results` div only, try this:

```js
var lookup = {
  '#': 'hash',
  '+': 'plus',
  '/': 'or'
}

var spanText = $('span').map(function() {
  var t = $(this).text();
  Object.keys(lookup).forEach(function(k) {
    t = t.replace(new RegExp('\\' + k, 'g'), lookup[k]);
  });
  return t;
}).get()
$('#results').text(spanText.join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="teks">A</span>
<span class="teks">B</span>
<span class="teks">C#</span>
<span class="teks">G#7+</span>
<span class="teks">Fm/Ab</span>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. It worked, but not replace text on a `<div id = "results"></ div>`

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex should do it.

```js
var str = 'I want to change all of the text is "#", "/", and "+" using JavaScript or jQuery.';

console.log(
  str
  .replace(/#/ig,'hash')
  .replace(/\//ig,'or')
  .replace(/\+/ig,'plus')
)
```

```html
I want to change all of the text is "#", "/", and "+" using JavaScript or jQuery.

How to change this to appear on <div id="results"></div> ?

# => hash

/ => or

+ => plus
```